# Get Dataset information in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have an Dataset (XSD) with many datatables. How can I get informations about this datatables? for example I want to get all columns and its captions from a specific datatable.
When I use **dataset_X.datatable_Y....**    there are no properties like "**colums**" and so on.
I only get "**Equals**", "**GetDataTableSchema**", "**GetTypedSchema**" and "**Reference Equals**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your strongly typed `DataSet`.

For example:

```
var ds = new dataset_X();
DataColumnCollection columns = ds.datatable_Y.Columns;
```

or, if you want informations of a specific column, you can also use the auto generated property. Assuming there's a column with a name `idSparePart`, there's automatically a property `idSparePartColumn`.

```
DataColumn col = ds.datatable_Y.idSparePartColumn;
String columnName = col.ColumName; 
Type t = col.DataType;
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `GetXmlSchema`

```
string schemaString = dataSet.GetXmlSchema();
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41732z18.aspx